# Filtering fields that can be added to Permission Set

Tags: metadata-api, permission-sets

We are writing a text file, called: `read-all-fields.permissionset-meta.xml`, which is meant to mimic all the fields that can be added to a Permission Set (across all objects)

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PermissionSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>AIApplication.Id</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>AIApplication.IsDeleted</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>AIApplication.DeveloperName</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
```

Is there any particular criteria - we can filter to make sure the fields can be added to the permission set so we don't get errors like:

```
{'state': 'Failed', 'state_detail': None, 'deployment_detail': {'total_count': '1', 'failed_count': '1', 'deployed_count': '0', 'errors': [{'type': 'PermissionSet', 'file': 'permissionsets/read-all-fields.permissionset-meta.xml', 'status': 'Error', 'message': 'You cannot deploy to a required field: myfield__mdt.Id'}]}, 'unit_test_detail': {'total_count': '0', 'failed_count': '0', 'completed_count': '0', 'errors': []}}
```

Answer (score 1):

For adding just read permission, it should be sufficient to check for `isNillable=true`. If the field is not nillable, it is required, and thus can't have its permissions changed. This is true even for the Id field, which reports `isNillable=false`, even though, obviously, you won't have an Id on insert. As such, I'm pretty sure this is the only flag you need to check.

Comment: so that helped, but still getting issues with `Location Fields` and other fields, are there any additional properties you'd suggest?